# How do I get to the third field goal with enough hp left?

Tags: achievements, rage

I am playing Rage for the first time and I am playing on Nightmare. At the moment, I try to get the third field goal at the watch tower with the ATV. However, in the "arena" where the highway begins, I encounter two cars that just blow my ATV up with homing missiles within a matter of seconds.

**Is it possible and if yes, how do I get to the watch tower with the defenseless ATV?**

Answer (score 1):

So after trying around some more I found out that you can actually have multiple cars outside. So it was a no brainer to drive both cars near that area, then to kill everyone with the armed cars and then drive through to the watch tower with the atv and finish the challenge.